# Why does mysql ignore option files in conf.d?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Using a fresh install of MySQL 5.7, I have done the following:

Created a test-mysql.cnf:

```
$ ll /etc/mysql/conf.d/
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun 23 17:22 ./
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Jun 23 17:21 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    8 Apr 20 03:04 mysql.cnf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   55 Apr 20 03:04 mysqldump.cnf
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root   25 Jun 23 17:22 test-mysql.cnf
```

See the contents just change sql mode

```
$ cat /etc/mysql/conf.d/test-mysql.cnf
[mysqld]
sql-mode="ANSI"
```

Restart the server

```
$ sudo service mysql restart
```

Check the mode was set
    $ mysql

```
$ SELECT @@sql_mode;
```

Returns the wrong thing. Default, as if nothing was set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added this to `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
sql-mode="ANSI"
```

and it worked.

It turns out the `test-mysql.cnf` had writeable permissions. Any files with writable permissions are ignored for security reasons. I had to do:

```
sudo chmod og-w /etc/mysql/conf.d/test-mysql.cnf
```

Which removes write privileges for others and groups.

Also, symbolic links don't appear to be read. And frustratingly, they are silently ignored. They don't even give a warning.

Comment: You'll probably think "of course" when I suggest this, but just to be sure you did restart MySQL after your earlier attempt, right? BTW why are you setting the sql_mode to an empty string? That clears all modes currently enabled. Maybe that's what you want, but FYI you could also consider explicitly setting the modes you want, e.g. `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`.

Comment: I fixed it now finally, it was permissions issues. I've updated the answer